# stored procedure versus queries for array concatanation

Tags: arrays, postgresql, python-3.x

I have a database with time series data split up into even sized chunks stored as arrays in postgres.

I need to arbitrarily extract ranges of them and concatenate the returned set into a single array. They have an offset field so given a start offset and length you can find any part of the set you are looking for.

Which is better:

1. To write queries that return each individual array and concatenate in software

or

2. Use a stored procedure that takes a start point and length and does the concatenation internally before returning the entire array

Answer (score 0):

“Better” is a rather unspecific adjective in this case.

If you are asking for aesthetic judgement, simplicity of code and mantainability, I don't feel in a position to pronounce a clear judgement. My gut feeling is that both are similar.

If you are asking about good performance, I'd advise you to run a simple test. But even without a test I'd say that both solutions are not optimal and you should write it as a single SQL statement.

If you are asking about portability, the answer depends on whether it is more important to port to another database (that would favor the application software solution) or to port to a different programming language (in that case, the solution in the database is preferable).